# Get visual column number with conceal feature

Tags: functions, conceal

One can use `col('$')` to get the length of the current cursor line. Further, one can use `virtcol('$')` to get the same length, but this returns the actual screen column. However, it ignores the conceal feature.

Is there any way to get the column number similar to `col()` and `virtcol()` that takes the conceal into account?

Comment: I think the answer to this is "no". At least, I have not figured out any way to do it.

Comment: No, and I think this is in the todo list to have this fixed. Also according to Bram, things like '|' should consider concealed items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way that I can figure out is to make a function which loops over all
the characters in the line and checks if it's concealed with
[`synconcealed()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#synconcealed%28%29).

This seems to work well for help files:

```
fun! VisualCol()
    let l:substract = 0
    for l:i in range(0, col('$'))
        if synconcealed('.', l:i)[0]
            let l:substract += 1
        endif
    endfor

    return virtcol('$') - l:substract
endfun
```

Comment: This seems to work well for getting the length of the concealed line, but it does not quite work as a substitute for `col()`. I would add an argument that is passed to `col` and `virtcol`. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: @KarlYngveLervåg Yeah, it could be expanded a bit :-) Feel free to edit!